# how to add a link for one date in a arrow with datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Cid is in array with links how to parse cid and put each value as a link instead url in the funtion in mrender ?

My code :

cid is an array with links

```
var cid = ["http://www.toto.com","http://www.titi.com"];
```

and here is my code with the datatable :

```
var data_in_table = {
    "cid" : cid,
    "aaData": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "aTargets": [0],
            "bSortable": true,
            "mRender": function (url, type, full,cid) {
                return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
            }
        },
        {
            "aTargets": [3],
            "bSortable": true,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return data;
            }
        }
    ]
};

console.log("data_table",data_table['aaData']);
data_in_table["aaData"] = data_table['aaData'];
$('#table_data').dataTable(data_in_table);
```

and i imagine that i would like something like this  :

```
var data_in_table = {
    "cid" : cid,
    "aaData": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "aTargets": [0],
            "bSortable": true,
            "mRender": function (url, type, full,cid) {
                return '<a href="' + cid[i] + '">' + url + '</a>';
            }
        },
        {
            "aTargets": [3],
            "bSortable": true,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return data;
            }
        }
    ]
};

console.log("data_table",data_table['aaData']);
data_in_table["aaData"] = data_table['aaData'];
$('#table_data').dataTable(data_in_table);
```

how to get the `i` ?

Comment: What is the data type of `cid`? And what is the link for?

Comment: cid is an array and the link are to go on an other webpage

Comment: What is the **i** for? In the other words, how do I know **i**th link I ought to render?

Comment: i would like to have a counter inside the mrender function

Comment: Anyway, what result do you need? Could you give us an exapmle with **input** and **output** you expected?